# como usar correctamente if, else if edit text?

Tags: java, android-studio, condiciones, else

tengo 2 edittext, y al presionar un botón quiero que diga algo asi:

opción 1:
edittext 1 vacio
edittext 2 vacio
resultado toast mensaje 1
(logrado en mi código)

opción 2:
edittext 1 no vacio
edittext 2 vacio
resultado toast mensaje 2
(logrado en mi código)

Esta opción no me funciona:

opción 3:
edittext 1 vacio
edittext 2 no vacio
resultado toast mensaje 3
(NO logrado en mi código)

opción 4
edittext 1 no vacio
edittext 2 no vacio
resultado toast mensaje 4
(logrado en mi código)

dejo mi código, más que un problema de programación, es un problema de lógica, como lo harían uds?

gracias!!

```
            String et1 = edt1.getText().toString();
            String et2 = edt2.getText().toString();
            


            if (et1.matches("")) {
                toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } else  {
                if (et2.matches("")) {
                    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                } else  {
                    if (et1.matches("")) {
                        toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    } else  {
                        toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer dos bloques porque tienes dos casos: cuando et1 es vacío y cuando no es vacío y en cada uno de ellos evalúas et2. Si et1 es vacío entonces, et2 es vacío o no vacío; de lo contrario, et1 no es vacío, entonces, vuelves a evaluar et2 para este caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según dices los requerimientos son:

1. **Mensaje1**: Si `texto1` y `texto2` están vacios
2. **Mensaje2**: Si `texto1` no está vacío `texto2` está vacío
3. **Mensaje3**: Si `texto1` está vacío y `texto2` no está vacío
4. **Mensaje4**: Si `texto1` y `texto2` no están vacios

Es más simple evaluar el contenido de ambos edittext junto, de lo contrario es un tremendo lío.

Veamos, en el mismo orden en que lo has indicado:

```
//Una variable para no repetir tanto el código del toast
String msg="";

if ( et1.matches("") && et2.matches("") ) {
    msg="mensaje 1";
} else if ( !et1.matches("") && et2.matches("") ) {
    msg="mensaje 2";
} else if ( et1.matches("") && !et2.matches("") ) {
    msg="mensaje 3";
//Si llega aquí es que se cumple el requisito 4
} else {
    msg="mensaje 4";
}                

//Usamos msg y mostramos la tostadora 
toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Funciona Perfecto! acabo de descubrir el "!" muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La opción 3 no te da bien porque no estas contemplando esa opción en el código. Cuando evalúa el primer `if`, al ser edittext 1 vacío, entra en el y no valora si edittext 2 es vació o no.

Al tener diferentes casos u opciones en tu código, es mejor implementarlo con el operador `&&` (AND). Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
String et1 = edt1.getText().toString();
String et2 = edt2.getText().toString();

% Opción 1 -  edittext 1 vacio edittext 2 vacio
if (et1.matches("") && et2.matches(""))
    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    
% Opción 2 - edittext 1 no vacio edittext 2 vacio
if (!et1.matches("") && et2.matches(""))
    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    
% Opción 3 -  edittext 1 vacio edittext 2 no vacio
if (et1.matches("") && !et2.matches(""))
    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    
% Opción 4 - edittext 1 no vacio edittext 2 no vacio
if (!et1.matches("") && !et2.matches(""))
    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mensaje 4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Este código lo puedes implementar también con cláusulas `else if` pero creo que así se ve mejor.

Por otra parte, para comprobar si un String es vacío o no puedes hacerlo de las siguietnes formas, siendo las tres métodos de la clase `String`:

- Usando el método `matches()` al cual se le pasa una expresión regular como parámetro. Documentación [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))
- Usando el método `equals()` al cual se le pasa un `String` como parámetro y lo compara tal cual, devolviendo true al pasarle un valor `null`. Documentación [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))
- Usando el método `isEmpty()` el cual evalúa si un `String` es de tamaño 0 o no. Este método, a diferencia del anterior, devolverá una excepción si le pasas un valor `null`. Documentación [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

La ventaja de usar `"".equals(str)` es que no necesitas comprobar si es un valor `null` o no. Si estas seguro de que no será nulo, puedes usarlo, en otro caso yo usaría `str.isEmpty()`

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por tu ayuda, te cuento que tambien probe tu código y funciona perfecto!, solo me deja votar por una sola respuesta, pero las 2 que me dieron uds. funcionan excelente!!